# NodeJS loop through string and get the exact output

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

In NodeJS I have a string like this

```
"Package=Package&Qty=1&Price=123?Package=Package Two&Qty=3&Price=702?Package=Package Three&Qty=1&Price=199?Package=Package One&Qty=4&Price=852?"
```

In the string you can see there are multiple Package, Qty and Price. Now I want to send email for each Qty and Package. So if you see Package Two it has Qty 3. So in that case there it will send 3 emails with Package and Price. So basically it will send email for each Qty with corresponding Package and Price.

So for now I have my code like this

```
var string = "Package=Package&Qty=1&Price=123?Package=Package Two&Qty=3&Price=702?Package=Package Three&Qty=1&Price=199?Package=Package One&Qty=4&Price=852?";
var packArr = string.split('?');
var PackageName;
var PackagePrice;
for (var i = 0; i < packArr.length; i++) {
  if( packArr[i].length > 0 ) {
    let packageQty = packArr[i].split('&');
    for (var j = 0; j < packageQty.length; j++) {
      if( packageQty[j].match(/Package=/i) ) {
        PackageName = packageQty[j].replace(/Package=/g,'');
          console.log(PackageName);
      }

      if( packageQty[j].match(/Price=/i) ) {
        PackagePrice = packageQty[j].replace(/Price=/g,'');
          console.log(PackagePrice);
      }

      if (packageQty[j].match(/Qty=/i)) {
        var ret = packageQty[j].replace(/Qty=/g,'');
        var Pck = Number(ret);
        for (var k = 1; k <= Pck; k++) {
          console.log(k);
          console.log('Package Name ' + PackageName);
          console.log('Package Price ' + PackagePrice);
          //send email with Package Name, Package Price 
          if( k == Pck ) {
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above code actually not working properly. It is not getting the Package and Price properly for each loop. So can someone tell me how to do this in a easy way? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to send N emails per package, but.. Take a look at my answer

Comment: I have requirement like that. BTW I haven't got answer from you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a much cleaner way using [querystring](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html) package

```
const string = "Package=Package&Qty=1&Price=123?Package=Package Two&Qty=3&Price=702?Package=Package Three&Qty=1&Price=199?Package=Package One&Qty=4&Price=852?";

const qs = require('querystring');

// We split the string into multiple valid query strings.
// We strip the empty item due to the '?' at the end using .filter(Boolean)
const items = string.split('?').filter(Boolean);

// We loop through each group
for(const query of items) {
    // Parse the query string of each group
    const { Package, Qty, Price } = qs.parse(query);

    for(let i = 0; i < Number(Qty); i++) {
        // We send the email here <Qty> times.
        console.log('Package Name ' + Package);
        console.log('Package Price ' + Price);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you answer my another question related to this? Here I am trying to save the output in mongodb.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49642112/nodejs-loop-through-the-string-and-save-into-mongodb-with-auto-increment-length

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you feel about libraries, but [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com) (disclaimer: I'm one of the authors) is well-suited to data-transformations.  And this screams for some straightforward data transformation.

I might use it to write a conversion function that changes your initial data into something like:

```
[
  {Package: "Package",       Price: 123, Qty: 1}, 
  {Package: "Package Two",   Price: 702, Qty: 3},
  {Package: "Package Three", Price: 199, Qty: 1}, 
  {Package: "Package One",   Price: 852, Qty: 4}
]
```

This new format should then be easy to work with.

Here is a implementation that does this:

```js
const {pipe, split, filter, map, fromPairs, evolve} = R;

const str = "Package=Package&Qty=1&Price=123?Package=Package Two&Qty=3&Price=702?Package=Package Three&Qty=1&Price=199?Package=Package One&Qty=4&Price=852?";

const convertToObjects = pipe(
  split('?'),
  filter(Boolean),
  map(split('&')),
  map(map(split('='))),
  map(fromPairs),
  map(evolve({Price: Number, Qty: Number}))
);

console.log(convertToObjects(str))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

- `map`, `split`, and `filter` should be obvious.
- `fromPairs` turns `[['a', 1], ['b', 2]]` into `{a: 1, b: 2}`.
- `evolve` takes a specification mapping property names to transformation functions, and transforms an object by applying those functions to the relevant properties, keeping all other properties intact.  Here we use it with the JS `Number` function to convert `{Package: 'Foo', Qty: '2', Price: '456'}` into `{Package: 'Foo', Qty: 2, Price: 456}`.
- and `pipe` creates a pipeline of functions in which the output of one function becomes the input to the next.  Values supplied to the resulting function are sent to the first one and the result of the last one is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Extending @[Marcos-casagrande](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1119863/marcos-casagrande) example here without external dependency using plain javascript

```js
const string = "Package=Package&Qty=1&Price=123?Package=Package Two&Qty=3&Price=702?Package=Package Three&Qty=1&Price=199?Package=Package One&Qty=4&Price=852?";

// We split the string into multiple valid query strings.
// We strip the empty item due to the '?' at the end using .filter(Boolean)
const items = string.split('?').filter(Boolean);

// We loop through each group
items.map(query => {
  // Parse the query string of each group
  const {
    Package,
    Qty,
    Price
  } = query.split('&').reduce((acc, cur) => {
    let arr = cur.split('=');
    return {
      ...acc,
      [arr[0]]: arr[1]
    };
  }, {});

  for (let i = 0; i < Number(Qty); i++) {
    // We send the email here <Qty> times.
    console.log('Package Name ' + Package);
    console.log('Package Price ' + Price);
  }
})
```

Comment: Have in mind that querystring is not an external dependency in node, where this question is tagged ;). Anyhow It will help someone, I would put it in a function though, it's quite hard to read that way.

Comment: Good to know, not a `node` person yet.

Answer (score 0):

Another way using only regexes and a few array methods, not requiring nested loops

```js
var input = "Package=Package&Qty=1&Price=123?Package=Package Two&Qty=3&Price=702?Package=Package Three&Qty=1&Price=199?Package=Package One&Qty=4&Price=852?"

var results = input
  .split('?')
  .map(s => /^Package=(.*?)&Qty=(.*?)&Price=(.*?)$/.exec(s))
  .filter(s => s)
  .map(s => ({ 
      package: s[1], 
      qty: parseFloat(s[2]), 
      price: parseFloat(s[3]) 
  }))

console.log(JSON.stringify(results, null, 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure JS alternative, please take a look.

```js
function extract(name, string) {
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
  var results = regex.exec(string);
  return results == null ? null : results[1];
}

function parse(string) {
  items = string.split('?');
  results = [];
  for (var i in items) {
    if (items[i].length == 0) continue;
    var item = '?' + items[i];
    results.push({
      package: extract("Package", item),
      qty: extract("Qty", item),
      price: extract("Price", item)
    })
  }
  return results;
}
str = "Package=Package&Qty=1&Price=123?Package=Package Two&Qty=3&Price=702?Package=Package Three&Qty=1&Price=199?Package=Package One&Qty=4&Price=852?";
document.getElementById('output').innerText = JSON.stringify(parse(str));
```

```html
<div id='output'></div>
```