# Nodejs loop through the string and save into mongodb with auto increment length

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

In NodeJS I have string like this

```
"Package=Package&Qty=1&Price=123?Package=Package Two&Qty=3&Price=702?Package=Package Three&Qty=1&Price=199?Package=Package One&Qty=4&Price=852?";
```

I want to save each Qty with corresponding Package and Price. So lets say I have Package Two with Qty 3 then it would save 3 times with Package Two and Price would be 702.

So for now my code looks like this

```
const querystring = require('querystring');
const string = "Package=Package&Qty=1&Price=123?Package=Package Two&Qty=3&Price=702?Package=Package Three&Qty=1&Price=199?Package=Package One&Qty=4&Price=852?";
const items = string.split('?').filter(Boolean);
var TicketCountQuery = Ticket.count();
for(const query of items) {
    // Parse the query string of each group
    const { Package, Qty, Price } = querystring.parse(query);

    for(let i = 0; i < Number(Qty); i++) {
        console.log('Package Name ' + Package);
        console.log('Package Price ' + Price);

        TicketCountQuery.exec(function (e, count) {
          if( count !== '' ) {
            let TicketId = parseInt(count) + 1;
            console.log(TicketId);
            let ticketData = new Ticket({
              _id           : new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
              ticketid      : 'TKT '+ TicketId,
              packagename   : Package,
              price         : Price
            });

            ticketData.save((err) => {
              if( err ) {
                if( err.errors ) {
                  console.log('something went wrong');
                }
              }
              else {
                console.log('tickets saved');
              }
            });
          }
        });
      }
    }
```

Here the problem is it is just checking the mongodb collection only for the first time. That's why the ticketid is always same. I want that ticketid should be increment for each insert. But somehow its not working. So can someone tell me how to do this?
Any help and suggestion will be really appreciable.

Comment: Just to be sure, `console.log(TicketId)` always print the same number? If so I know why, without being too familiar with mongodb.

Comment: Yes it prints the same number always

Comment: done, let me know if it worked, I have no way to test it, so patience ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're running the N exec queries before saving any ticket, this happens because the `mongoose.exec` runs asynchronously, so all the queries will return the same `count`. An easy fix is using `async/await`. According to the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html), `.exec` returns a promise if no callback is supplied, so we can easilly wait until the exec is done using `await`

```
const string = "Package=Package&Qty=1&Price=123?Package=Package Two&Qty=3&Price=702?Package=Package Three&Qty=1&Price=199?Package=Package One&Qty=4&Price=852?";

const qs = require('querystring');

async function processTickets(string) {

    const TicketCountQuery = Ticket.count();

    // We split the string into multiple valid query strings.
    // We strip the empty item due to the '?' at the end using .filter(Boolean)

    const items = string.split('?').filter(Boolean);

    // We loop through each group
    for(const query of items) {
        // Parse the query string of each group
        const { Package, Qty, Price } = qs.parse(query);

        for(let i = 0; i < Number(Qty); i++) {
            // We send the email here <Qty> times.
            console.log('Package Name ' + Package);
            console.log('Package Price ' + Price);

            try {
                // We wait until exec is done
                // No other tickets can be fetched/saved, preventing your problem
                const count = await TicketCountQuery.exec();

                if( count !== '' ) {

                    let TicketId = parseInt(count) + 1;

                    let ticketData = new Ticket({
                        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                        ticketid: 'TKT ' + TicketId,
                        packagename: Package,
                        price: Price
                    });

                    // We save each ticket one at a time
                    // So the next one will have the correct ID.
                    await ticketData.save();
                    console.log('ticket saved');
                }

            } catch(e) {
                console.log('something went wrong', e);
            }
        }
    }

}

processTickets(string)
    .then(res => {
        console.log('Tickets processed!')
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err)
    })
```

Comment: where should I define TicketCountQuery?

Comment: Oh I forgot about that, At the top of processTickets, edited my answer.

Comment: Okay thanks. For now its working. Will accept answer after some testings. Thanks for the help. You are a genius. :)

Comment: Excellent and thanks! Never used mongo before :), I'll take an upvote until you run your test an accept the answer ;)